# why concat never() in rxswift

Tags: ios, rx-swift, reactive

```
func signup(_ username: String, password: String) -> Observable<Bool> {
    // this is also just a mock
    let signupResult = arc4random() % 5 == 0 ? false : true
    return Observable.just(signupResult)
        .concat(Observable.never())
        .throttle(0.4, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .take(1)
 }
```

I see some code in [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/GitHubSignup/DefaultImplementations.swift), But I could not understand why need to `concat(Observable.never())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making sense of this myself, so take it with a grain of salt :)

- `Observable.just` emits the value once and completes immediately; it takes virtually no time at all;
- `.throttle(0.4, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)` introduces time into the sequence, taking 0.4s+ to determine the value to return, and
- `concat(Observable.never())` makes the input sequence long-running so `throttle` has something to do in the first place.

Now `return Observable.just(signupResult)` would suffice to implement that function. What's the rest good for?

The other three operators result in a delay. Since the concatenated Observable is never-ending, `throttle` will wait at least 0.4 seconds once to determine which value to emit for the first throttled "chunk". `take(1)` then completes the sequence once the first value is emitted after 0.4s

To me, this seems to be a very laborious way to implement a delayed response :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just example. FUI, `never` create an Observable that emits no items and does not terminate (description from [official documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/empty-never-throw.html))

Comment: Thank you，I know the usage of `never`,so I don`t understand why use never(),so this is just example~

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @ctietze seems right. But after make a test, I realize that `throttle` kills the whole concept.
Basically `throttle` will return the value right after the observable start. That mean it won't wait until `0.4s` to emit the first value.

```
func testWithThrottle() -> Observable<Int> {
        return
            Observable.just(7) // 1
                .concat(Observable.never()) // 2
                .throttle(3.0, scheduler: Schedulers.background) // 3
                .take(1) // 4

        // 1. -7--|->
        // 2. -7------------------------------->
        // 3. -7------------------------------->
        // 4. -7--|->
}

...

print("[\(Date())] Start!")
testWithThrottle().subscribe({ (event) in
    print("[\(Date())] event: \(event)")
}).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
print("[\(Date())] End!")

...

[2017-06-03 03:14:00 +0000] Start!
[2017-06-03 03:14:00 +0000] event: next(7)
[2017-06-03 03:14:00 +0000] event: completed
[2017-06-03 03:14:00 +0000] End!
```

SO, what is the solution? Easy, you need to use `debounce` instead.

```
func testWithDebounce() -> Observable<String> {
        return
            Observable.of("A") // 1
                .concat(Observable.never()) // 2
                .debounce(3.0, scheduler: Schedulers.background) // 3
                .take(1) // 4

        // 1. -A-|->
        // 2. -A------------------------------>
        // 3. ---------------A---------------->
        // 4. ---------------A-|->
}

...

[2017-06-03 03:24:21 +0000] Start Thrrotle!
[2017-06-03 03:24:21 +0000] Finish Thrrotle!
[2017-06-03 03:24:24 +0000] event: next(A)
[2017-06-03 03:24:24 +0000] event: completed
```